# Adding a toggle box to d3.js Indented Tree Graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is it possible to add a checkable box to rows in this d3.js indented tree graph? http://bl.ocks.org/1093025[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in checkbox for svg, so you will need to create your own using svg elements that do exist.

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brantolsen/X2hbX/) that uses the `circle` element to do this. To do this, I took the example you linked and added the following:

```
// Add checkbox
nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
.attr("r", 5)
.attr("fill", "white")
.on("click", function(d) {
    if (d.selected) {
        d.selected = false;
        d3.select(this).attr("fill", "white");
    } else {
        d.selected = true;
        d3.select(this).attr("fill", "black");
    }
});
```

To access the list of selected nodes, add the following function and call it

```
function printSelectedNodes() {
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root);

  var selected = [];
  nodes.forEach(function(n, i) {
    if (n.selected) {
      selected.push(n.name);
    }
  });
  console.log(selected);
}
```

Comment: This is absolutely sweet. Thank you so much. My only question would be how do I read whether a toggle is selected or not?

Comment: Updated both the fiddle and the above code to show you how to access the toggle information.